# Find the solution of the following second order nonlinear ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was asked by my friend to solve an ODE which is reduced to the following form: $\frac{d^2 y}{d t^2} exp(2y) + f(t) =0 $
where $f(t)$ is a given positive function.

But I cannot go further. Would you give me any suggestions to deal with this type of second order nonlinear ODE ?

Comment: What is  the original ODE?

Comment: @themaker See the comment under my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general method for solving $y''+f(t)e^{-2y}=0$. You can find a solution numerically, or you can study some qualitative properties of the solutions. (In the latter case, you should specify what qualitative properties are of interest.)

Consider this: the solutions of much simpler, *linear* equation $y''-ty=0$ are Airy functions, which are defined ... well, as solutions of this equation.

Comment: In fact, this comes from the following: $ xx''-(x')^2 + \frac{1}{f(t)^2} =0 $

Comment: @hkju:  How do you get from $xx'' -(x')^2 + \frac{1}{f(t)^2}$ to $e^{2y} y'' + f(t) = 0$?  I could probably figure this out myself, but my plate is overfull right now, so if you could "show and tell" as it were, that would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: I should have written down as $ f(x)$ in stead of $\frac{1}{f(x)^2}$. Sorry, Lewis.

Comment: :hkju You should notify a user like this: @RobertLewis

Comment: @Robert Lewis: I should have written down as $ f(x)$ in stead of $\frac{1}{f(x)^2}$. Sorry, Lewis.

Comment: Here, I am not trying to find the solution of the linearised equation of the given ODE. I am only interested in the exact solution via any particular change of variable(s).

Comment: @hkju Nowadays, computers are better at that task than people. I tried your equation with Maple and it did not succeed.

Comment: @hkju:  I see.  So I guess you set $x(t) = e^{y(t)}$ whence $x'(t) = y'(t)e^{y(t)}$ whence $x''(t) = y''(t)e^{y(t)} + (y'(t))^2e^{y(t)}$ whence $x(t)x''(t) = y''(t)e^{2y(t)} + (y'(t))^2e^{2y(t)} = y''(t)e^{2y(t)} + (x'(t))^2$ whence $x(t)x''(t) - (x'(t))^2 = y''(t)e^{2y(t)}$ whence $y''e^{2y} + f(t) = 0$.  Right?

Comment: @Robert Lewis: Correct! If $f(x)=c^2$, where $c$ is constant, $y(t)=ln(sinh(ct))$ is a solution of the given equation above. That is, $x(t)=sinh(ct)$ is a solution of the equation $xx''-(x')^2+c^2=0$.